# Create alist of Async objects for F# parallel processing

Tags: f#

I know this is not very F# like, but I would like to do the following

```
[a; b; c; d]
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> ignore
```

where a, b, c and d are generated by a function like this

```
let myasync (stringparameter: string) =  [async{some_code}]
```

where some_code is for getting information from Internet and saving to database.  The function itself should return nothing (returns unit).

I want to create [a,b,c,d] by using

```
let mutable mylist = []
for i in [1..n] do
   myfunction
   mylist <- List.append mylist myfunction
```

I got the error:  The expression was expected to have type 'a list' but here has type 'string -> Async list'

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the value for `stringparameter`? Is it the same for all generated functions?

Comment: Stuart''s second solution works perfectly for me.  I was able to get a list of <Async>.  I tried to do something similar but did not know I had to use the yield keyword.

@SergeyBerezovskiy stringparameter is actually from a global variable which absolutely does not play nice with async parallel.  I am rewriting the function now so that it will work more F# like.  As of now, I do not get the intended effect but I am marking this question as answered because this step is finished. I have another question for the rewrite actually =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate error you are seeing is because `List.append` wants 2 `list` parameters, it's not like `Array.Add()`, you can fix it by doing the following:

```
let mutable mylist = []
for i in [1..n] do
   myfunction
   mylist <- List.append mylist [myfunction]
```

However, there are more succinct ways to do this without using mutability. Example:

```
let mylist =
    [ for i in [1..n] do
            let myfunction() =
                async {
                    // your code
                    return () }
            yield myfunction ]
```